# Google Doubleclick - custom video source after initial load

Tags: javascript, html5-video, double-click-advertising

I'm trying to polite load a video for a HTML5 creative served though google Doubleclick Studio and running into some issues

```
                    <video id="myVideo">
                      <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
```

This works fine

Now, when I try to dynamically add the source

```
'HTML' 

                    <video id="myVideo">                          
                    </video>

'JS'

                    source = document.createElement('source')
                    source.setAttribute('type', 'video/mp4')
                    source.setAttribute('src', 'video.mp4')
                    video.appendChild(source)
```

Doubleclick will give me this error

```
GET https://s0.2mdn.net/ads/richmedia/studio/pv2/60863002/20181009012818318/video.mp4 404
```

I suspect this is related to where Doubleclick stores the assets during initial load, because when I try to log the 'src' attribute using the first method, I get this tongue twister:

```
https://gcdn.2mdn.net/videoplayback/id/0173366851186f65/itag/15/source/doubleclick/ratebypass/yes/mime/video%2Fmp4/acao/yes/ip/0.0.0.0/ipbits/0/expire/3683521965/sparams/id,itag,source,ratebypass,mime,acao,ipbits,expire/signature/79EA6270A42AF05325924BB711068AE6A1943312.29D8F6E2DB82F38750A45593094A36C9BBC74D04/key/ck2/file/file.mp4
```

This explains the 404, however, I don't have this problem on my local PC.

How do I tell Doubleclick where to find my video.mp4 file so I can load it after the initial load

Comment: Specify an absolute URL …?

Answer (score 1):

When a video is uploaded to DoubleClick Studio, it's type is listed as a Video Bundle in the Assets listing. DoubleClick actually [transcodes the video](https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/6103833?hl=en) into multiple formats and bitrates automatically.

In production mode, when you request the video using a relative URL in your banner it will return a 404 as you have experienced.

[DoubleClick Enabler SDK](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/docs/sdk/html5/en/class_studio_Enabler.html) contains a method named `Enabler.getUrl`. This only works in live mode (including DC Studio preview mode) and will return an absolute URL from their CDN. When testing locally you still need to reference the file relatively like normal.

To assist with this there is another method in the SDK called `Enabler.isServingInLiveEnvironment` which allows you to determine whether you are in "live" mode or not.

Here's an example of combining the two SDK calls to request the correct video URL for the current environment.

```
function getVideoUrl(filename) {
    if (Enabler.isServingInLiveEnvironment()) {
        return Enabler.getUrl(filename); 
    } else {
        return filename;
    }
}

myVideo.src = getVideoUrl('myVideo.mp4');
```